# Get latest Date Record mysql

Tags: mysql

timestamp_read timestamp entity_id status currently_in

```
10/26/16 15:31  1477495880  1758    0   36 West
11/1/16 19:08   1478027336  1758    0   36 West
11/28/16 19:42  1480362171  1758    0   36 West
12/17/16 16:50  1481993441  1758    0   36 West
1/10/17 21:17   1484083045  1758    1   36 West
11/18/16 19:56  1479499012  1841    0   Service
12/7/16 16:33   1481128427  1841    0   Attention
11/4/16 15:05   1478271946  1902    0   36 West
11/28/16 16:47  1480351626  1902    0   36 West
12/16/16 23:49  1481932191  1902    0   36 West
1/10/17 21:32   1484083954  1902    1   36 West
11/1/16 18:54   1478026491  1904    0   36 West
11/28/16 17:28  1480354089  1904    0   36 West
12/17/16 18:09  1481998170  1904    0   36 West
12/21/16 14:53  1482332016  1904    0   55 West
1/6/17 19:34    1483731252  1904    0   Show
1/11/17 16:01   1484150479  1904    0   55 West
1/17/17 17:31   1484674280  1904    1   36 West
```

I have to audit a LOG on not the best designed table.

I need the latest record from column 'entity' based on a unixtime column 'timestamp'

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: No pictures thanks. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please share what you have already tried. @mcortes

Answer (score 0):

`select * from scan_log order by timestamp desc limit 1`

Is that what you want? You haven't described any foreign keys or relations.